# Inserting hyphens into length limited String using regex

Tags: swift, regex

Within a Swift project I have some regex which at present ensures that an input can only be 10 characters long:

```
"^[\\da-zA-Z]{10,10}$"
```

I need to tweak this slightly, so that the string which this is working on will have the below format:

```
#####-####
```

i.e, inserting a character after the fifth character.

So far I have tried combining what I have with some other regex, however this is incorrect and I can't figure out what I need to do differently to make this work:

```
"^[\\da-zA-Z]{10,10}$(.{5}),$1-$2"
```

Comment: Just use: `^([\\da-zA-Z]{5})([\\da-zA-Z]{5})$` and replace with `$1-$2`

Comment: Apologies - new to regex. Where should I be replacing here?

Comment: @anubhava I don't think this is about replacing so your suggested regex should be `^([\\da-zA-Z]{5})-([\\da-zA-Z]{4})$`. So 5 letters or digits then a dash and then another 4 letters or digits

Comment: Can you add concrete examples of the input data and the corresponding expected output? @davedave1919

Comment: Please add the code to the question, and provide a single real life example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have as string of 10 characters and you want to replace the character after the sixth character you could use 2 capturing groups.

Capture the first 5 characters in the first group, then match the sixth character which you want to replace and capture the last 4 in the second group.

```
^([\\da-zA-Z]{5})[\\da-zA-Z]([\\da-zA-Z]{4})$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9UmP80/1)

In the replacement use `$1-$2` which in total will be 10 characters as in your desired pattern `#####-####`

**Note** that `{10,10}` can be written as `{10}`